# Close session and redirect to login in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session-timeout

I am working with `session[:hash_name]` in ruby on rails to keep session information such as username and stuff.

I am trying to find a way to expire this session without the user having to log out. Specially in two cases: after some time it needs to expire and when the user closes the browser.

So far I have found [another](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-session-cookies.htm) parameter called `cookies[:hash_name]` which can expire after some time. But I'm not sure how to check this parameter in every user request and then call reset_session. When the session is reset I need to redirect the user to the login page.

Any suggestion to solve these 2 problems are greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the session in a cookie, which is a session cookie by default (meaning it goes away when the user closes the browser), and add an expiration time using `:expire_after`.

This can be configured in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`.   For example:

```
Yourapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
                                         key: 'your_session_id',
                                         expire_after: 45.minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

Well im pretty sure that if you run `session.delete(:hash_name)` that will destroy the session, however it is highly recommended that you don't try to build your own authentication system, especially when it will take you hours to build the most basic functionality, whereas a pre-built solution could be installed in 20 minutes. Not only that, but the pre-built solution is probably twice as secure as anything you can cook up yourself because its been tested and tested by myriad of developer.

I would highly recommend using devise for authentication. With devise you get methods such as `sign_out(current_user)`, which obviously signs out the user that made the request. Take a look at [devise's github page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

All it takes is `gem install devise`, add it to your gemfile, and then run

`rails g devise:install User # or whatever model name`

And they handle the rest

Comment: Thank you, I'll explore the option of using devise, but for now I needed a simple session controller that expires after some time. Answer which I received by "Old Pro"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using your own custom authentication method. So, for scenario1(i.e. expiring session after some times), you can do something similar to given below:

```
def create_session
  if session[:hash_key]
    destroy_session if session[:last_login] < 10.minutes.ago
    session[:last_login] = Time.now
  else
    ... authenticate
    session[:last_login] = Time.now
  end
end

def destroy_session
  reset_session
end
```

For scenario2(i.e on browser close), you can call use jquery event handler and can do something like below:

```
$('window').unload(function(){
  //call to destroy session method
});
```